# GeoLocation in a webview inside a Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get geolocation inside a webview in a Chrome Packaged App, in order to run my application properly. I've tried several ways to get the permission in manifest.json and injecting scripts, but it doesn't work and doesn't show any error message.

Could someone give me a light or a solution to get permission and show my geolocation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some features that usually require permissions in a normal web page are also available in a webview. However, instead of the normal popup "the website xyz.com wants to know your physical location - allow / deny", the app that contains the webview needs to explicitly authorize it. Here is how it works:

- No need to change the web page inside the webview;
- In the app, you listen for `permissionrequest` events on the `<webview>` element:

```js
webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', function(e) {
  if ( e.permission === 'geolocation' ) {
    e.request.allow();
  } else {
    console.log('Denied permission '+e.permission+' requested by webview');
    e.request.deny();
  }
});
```

One thing to note is that the request doesn't need to be handled immediately. You can do whatever you need to do before allowing or denying, as long as you call `preventDefault` in the permissionrequest event and keep the event object from being garbage collected. This is useful if you need to do any async operation, like going to a storage to check if the URL requesting a permission should be allowed or not.

For example:

```js
webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', function(e) {
  if ( e.permission === 'geolocation' ) {
    // Calling e.preventDefault() is necessary to delay the response.
    // If the default is not prevented then the default action is to
    // deny the permission request.
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() { decidePermission(e); }, 0);
  }
});

var decidePermission = function(e) {
  if (e.url == 'http://www.google.com') {
    e.request.allow();
  }
  // Calling e.request.deny() explicitly is not absolutely necessary because
  // the request object is managed by the Javascript garbage collector.
  // Once collected, the request will automatically be denied.
  // If you wish to deny immediately call e.request.deny();
}
```

- Also note that your app needs to also request the respective permission:

```json
"permissions": ["geolocation"],
```

The [webview sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/webview/index.js#L61-L72) has more code for other permissions, like pointerLock and media capture.

Comment: UPDATE: added @user2296820 information about delayed approval/denying of permission request

Comment: Good morning!
Mangini I thought I had solved the problem with your code, but after I published the application to install some of my friends were not working.
I realized that only working in chrome canary ... did some testing to force the display in normal location can get, but it does not display at all.
You know enter a reason?
Link Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localizeime/ihappndkmffngabclkkpebgnbchlbhjg?utm_source=plus
 there you can find the files on github

Comment: It is working in Canary but not in other browsers? What version of the other browser? There are several improvements in webview on dev (chrome 27+), and permissionrequest is one of them. You won't be able to run this snippet on Chrome versions below 27.

Comment: My chrome version is the standard version 27.0.1453.73 beta-m and still does not work, the canary version works perfectly.

Comment: So you are probably using a 28-only feature. You can set a   "minimum_chrome_version": "28" field in your manifest, so people won't be able to install it unless they have the appropriate version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more detail:

The response does not need to be made immediately as long as you preventDefault(). The default action is to deny the permission request.

```
webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', function(e) {
  if ( e.permission === 'geolocation' ) {
    // Calling e.preventDefault() is necessary to delay the response.
    // If the default is not prevented then the default action is to
    // deny the permission request.
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() { decidePermission(e); }, 0);
  }
});

var decidePermission = function(e) {
  if (e.url == 'http://www.google.com') {
    e.request.allow();
  }
  // Calling e.request.deny() explicitly is not absolutely necessary because
  // the request object is managed by the Javascript garbage collector.
  // Once collected, the request will automatically be denied.
  // If you wish to deny immediately call e.request.deny();
}
```